# Understanding batch size, sequence, sequence length and batch length of a RNN

Tags: rnn, pytorch

### My Problem

I'm struggling with the different definitions of batch size, sequence, sequence length and batch length of a RNN and how to use it in the correct way.

### First things first - let's clarify the definitions

Consider the following data with two features and two labels.

| timestamp | feature 1 | feature 2 | label 1 | label 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | f1.1 | f2.1 | l1.1 | l2.1 |
| t2 | f1.2 | f2.2 | l1.2 | l2.2 |
| t3 | f1.3 | f2.3 | l1.3 | l2.3 |
| t4 | f1.4 | f2.4 | l1.4 | l2.4 |
| t5 | f1.5 | f2.5 | l1.5 | l2.5 |
| t6 | f1.6 | f2.6 | l1.6 | l2.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Let us assume the system which I want to train in the RNN process always the current and the two previous time stamps. The following examples of definitions refer to this framework.

**Definition Training Example:**
A training is setup of trainings data which is processed by the neural network at once.
*Example:* `[f1.1, f2.1]`

**Definition Sequence:**
A Sequence is a setup of several trainings data which are processed in a row to the network.
*Example:*

```
[[f1.1, f2.1], 
 [f1.2, f2.2],
 [f1.3, f2.3]]
```

**Definition Sequence number:**
The number of training examples which needed to be processed as sequence by the RNN is called sequence number.
*Example:* `3`

**Definition Batch Size:**
The batch size is the number of sequences which are forward to the RNN before the gradients are calculated.
*Example:*

```
[[[f1.1, f2.1], 
  [f1.2, f2.2],
  [f1.3, f2.3]],
 
 [[f1.2, f2.2], 
  [f1.3, f2.3],
  [f1.4, f2.4]], 
 
 [[f1.3, f2.3], 
  [f1.4, f2.4],
  [f1.5, f2.5]]
 
 [[f1.4, f2.4], 
  [f1.5, f2.5],
  [f1.6, f2.6]]
]
```

**Definition Batch Length:**
The total number of batches are the batch length.
*Example:* `1` in the previous example.

**Definition Data Length:**
The total number training examples is calculated by the batch length times batch size times sequence number.
*Example:* `3 * 4 * 1` of the previous examples.

### Second - implementation with pyTorch

For the implementation of my RNN I use pyTorch with the following code as an example. However, if my previous definition are right, I'm unable to transfer them to the code. I have always errors with the tensor dimensions.

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, sequence_length):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers  = num_layers
        self.batch_size  = sequence_length
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * sequence_length, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden_state = torch.zeros(x.size(0), self.num_layers, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        out, _ = self.rnn(x, hidden_state)
        out = out.reshape(out.shape[0], -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

### Questions

1. Are the definitions correct?
2. How should the hidden_state initialized correctly by considering the batch size, batch number, sequence, sequence number, hidden size and hidden layer size?
3. What shape should be x in the forward method, assuming x represents the complete or parts of the previous data example.

Please help me to solve the puzzle, in the best case with an example for x and the hidden_state based on my example.

Many thanks.

---

I'm asking a second question on this topic ((RNN with PyTorch - I don't understand the initial parameters)[https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/121817/rnn-with-pytorch-i-dont-understand-the-initial-parameters/121919#121919])  and the answer answers those questions as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.